# Catkin_make with Gcov

Tags: gcov, catkin

These days I have tried so hard to test my rosapp. I want to use Gcov when testing my rosapp. However, I am not so familiar with that. I have tried to add Gcov in my CMakeList.txt but no .gcda files were generated. Does anyone konw how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The following options can be passed to [catkin tools](https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to add coverage instrumentation to the files within your catkin workspace:

```
$ catkin config --cmake-args \
  -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="--coverage" \
  -DCMAKE_LD_FLAGS="--coverage"
```